# How to get Id of checkbox for Checked one

Tags: jquery

On click of a button i am trying to get all the id's for which checkbox is checked in

I have tried it this way

```
<div class="propsContent">
   <ul id="equipdetails">
      <li>
         <div class="col-lg-8"><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt" id="123"><input type="checkbox">A<span></span></label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="exercise-img"><img src=""></div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="col-lg-8"><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline exercise-txt" id="456"><input type="checkbox">B<span></span></label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="exercise-img"><img src=""></div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<button value="GetAllValues" id="Button2" >GetAllValues</button>
```

**Js Code**

```
$(document).on("click", "#Button2", function(event)
{
        $('#equipdetails').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
        {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
});
```

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/706/

Could you please let me know how to get all checkbox id for all checked one's

Comment: None of your checkboxes have `id` attributes...?

Comment: there is no attr id in the checkboxes

Comment: @guradio , thanks solved it by your way  .

Answer (score 1):

Id is assigned to parent element try this:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#Button2", function(event)
      {
     $('#equipdetails').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
        {
            console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
        });
   });
```

check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/708/)